# MongoDB connection problem with Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Recently I'm using Docker and host it to our Dedicated Server everything is working fine,But Issue is we have made and absolute URL for mongodb here is our link below. I put mongodb URL in .env file

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@<serverip>:27017/<dbname>?authSource=admin
```

This URL is accessible without docker, we have existing project in our server with this given URL and it is working. I did not use mongodb in our docker, it is installed globally in our server. Is there any suggestion ??

Comment: are you trying to access the MongoDB from inside a container?

Comment: Yes Exactly.I kept MongoDB URL in .env file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the MongoDB from inside a container, replace the  with the name of the service in you docker-compose file.

So if your docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: "2"

services:
  mymongodb:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb:/data/db:z
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:27017:27017
    restart: always
```

your connection string looks like this: `mongodb://<username>:<password>@mymongodb:27017/<dbname>?authSource=admin`

Comment: Hello Thomas, Nope, We have already installed mongodb in our system, I need to connect it from outside of docker container.

Comment: Ah I understand, than maybe this solves your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/57833573#57833573